# Replace Title, Object and Society in my Word cover page and header?

Tags: powershell, ms-word, docx

I generate many docx documentations from HTML wiki tanks to pandoc. I add a cover page thanks to a power shell script. This cover page is a "template". This is not a real word template, but a page with a AAA_Title_AAA, AAA_Object_AAA and AAA_Society_AAA. The society is on the header too.

with the code below, I am able to replace any text inside my document, but not the Title / Object, nor society. Here is my code :

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
$objWord.Visible = $false

$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($args[0]) 
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection 

$FindText = $args[1] 
$MatchCase = $False 
$MatchWholeWord = $true
$MatchWildcards = $False 
$MatchSoundsLike = $False 
$MatchAllWordForms = $False 
$Forward = $True 
$Wrap = $wdFindContinue 
$Format = $False 
$wdReplaceNone = 0 
$ReplaceWith = $args[2] 
$wdFindContinue = 1 
$wdReplaceAll = 2

$a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, ` 
$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,` 
$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith,$wdReplaceAll) 
$objDoc.Save()
$objWord.Quit()
```

My cover page looks like this. My company force me to add it before every document :

[image: cover page]

How can I do please ?

Comment: For changing text inside textboxes, you'll have to dig deeper. Get the list of shapes: `$objSelection.Document.Shapes` and loop over them. For each of these shapes, get the `.TextFrame.TextRange` property and do the Find/Replace on that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it works a complete different way. I unzip the docx , I rename all string inside the folder , rezip the file and rename it as a docx and it works :

```
$fichier = $args[0]
$FindText = $args[1] 
$ReplaceWith = $args[2] 

Copy-Item $fichier -Destination '.\TMP.zip'

expand-archive -path '.\TMP.zip' -destinationpath '.\unzipped'

$configFiles = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse  '.\unzipped' 
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "$FindText", "$ReplaceWith" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}

compress-archive -path '.\unzipped\*' -destinationpath ".\TMP_edit.zip"

Remove-Item -Path "$fichier"
Remove-Item ".\unzipped" -Recurse
Remove-Item ".\TMP.zip"

Rename-Item -Path ".\TMP_edit.zip" -NewName "$fichier"
```